# MarkLogic spring RestTemplate

Tags: spring-mvc, marklogic, marklogic-8

Hi I am trying to get the list of graphs in MarkLogic using RestTemplate.
Below is the sample code. From the browser I can able to get the graph list, but through the Java REST Client I am getting error 401.

```
HttpHeaders header = new HttpHeaders();
String plainCreds = "restadmin:restpassword";
byte[] plainCredsBytes = plainCreds.getBytes();
byte[] base64CredsBytes = Base64.encode(plainCredsBytes);
String base64Creds = new String(base64CredsBytes);
header.setAccessControlAllowCredentials(true);
header.add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Creds);
header.setAccept(Arrays.asList(MediaType.TEXT_XML));
header.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_XML);
HttpEntity<String> entity = new HttpEntity<String>(header);

String url = "http://localhost:8003/v1/graphs";
ResponseEntity response = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, String.class);
System.out.println("Response : "+response.getStatusCode());
```

Please help me in resolving the issue

Comment: Why are you using the REST API directly and not the Java Client API? The latter abstracts away all of the HTTP underpinnings.

Comment: I am trying to run SPARQL query as mentioned in https://docs.marklogic.com/REST/POST/v1/graphs/sparql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try copying the HTTP auth code at https://github.com/rjrudin/ml-app-deployer/blob/master/src/main/java/com/rjrudin/marklogic/rest/util/RestTemplateUtil.java#L18 - I know it will handle HTTP basic auth against the management API on port 8002, and it should work fine on your REST API server on port 8003.

Comment: @Logesh, if this answer worked for you, please accept it -- that helps us see which questions still need more help.